# How to filter text after webscraping

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

So I'm trying to webscrape this website that provides novels for free, for example this page: https://www.wuxiaworld.com/novel/martial-world/mw-chapter-1

I'm trying to only extract the title and the body of the chapter. Finding the title is easy enough since its in h4, however the body of the chapter is not separated by any specific div tags so I cannot just isolate it. I was wondering how I'd do this. The closest Ive gotten to just having the text is this.

Ps. Im new to webscraping, sorry if my question is unclear or stupid.

I tried to identify if the body of text was under any exclusive div tag but it wasn't, so i tried to call it under whatever the closest div tag was, this still returned a lot of useless and unwanted text.

edit : @koro, there's more than one instance of fr-view being used so it doesn't isolate the text. fr-view class also appears before the chapter text.

Comment: please include your current code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not versed in webscraping but upon reviewing the page source html I see that `<div class="fr-view">` only precedes the body text on the novel pages. If you start the logging after the scraper identifies this line you should be able to stop at the very next `<a href="/novel.....` tag to only have the novel text included.

Some of the pages I see also include footnotes with some extra information, these include an `<a href=#footnote....>` tag, so if you would like to keep the footnotes included I would search for `<a href=/novel...>` and NOT `<a href=...>`

P.S. I only looked at 4 pages and while they all appear to have the same format that I've pointed out above it's still possible that you may run into issues, but that's definitely something you can a bridge you can cross when you get there!